# .htaccess redirect with parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

A page on my website, has the url is "http://example.com/image/33434".

To share this on a social network site, I want to shrink it down. I already have a domain where if you type in "http://exp.co/image/33434" it will redirect you, but I would like the short url to be "http://exp.co/i/33434".

Can this be done with a .htaccess file?

Thanks, Josh.

Comment: Did neither of these solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If example.com and exp.co are different hosts on the same application then do this:-

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}      ^exp\.co$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^i/([^/]+)/?$     http://example.com/image/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

If they are different applications then all you need is:-

```
RewriteRule ^i/([^/]+)/?$     http://example.com/image/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess.. or with a symbolic link.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase  /i/
RewriteRule ^([^\.].*)$ /image/$0 [L]
```